# Git instaweb with multiple repositories not working

Tags: git, instaweb

I have the following estructure which is populated via grok mirror:

```
/var/opt/git/git-data/repositories
   /organization1  
      /teamA
        /repo1
        /repo2
      /teamB
        /repo3
        /repo4
  /organizationN          
      /teamN
        /repoN
```

git instaweb works fine for a individual repo but if I want to automatically git instaweb shows all repos under "repositories" dir it doesnt' work:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/opt/git/git-data)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Which is true because there is no repo in the parent directory, but if I execute `git instaweb` from `/var/opt/git/git-data/repositories/organization/teamA/`  I get the same error and inside that directory is where the bare repos resides (a repoN.git directory for each repo)

I have set `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM` env var without results.
Also I have set `/etc/gitweb.conf` the following entry: `our $projectroot = "/var/opt/git/git-data/repositories";`

As I have read in doc of the project, git instaweb can serve for multiple repos, not only one and it looks for repos under certain directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think it can browse multiple repositories at the same time.

Comment: The doc shows that it's possible: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb
 Gitweb provides a web interface to Git repositories. Its features include:
Viewing multiple Git repositories with common root.

Comment: There is a workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348407/how-visualice-multiples-repos-and-clone-them-git-instaweb-gitlist-gitlab/38348437#38348437) to archive the same results.

Answer (score 6):

I do this by creating an empty repository and linking to the repositories I want to browse. This workaround is necessary because of the complicated way instaweb runs gitweb and sets the project root.

```
git init instaweb
cd instaweb
ln -s /var/opt/git/git-data/repositories/org1/teama/repo1 repo1-a-1
ln -s /var/opt/git/git-data/repositories/org2/teamb/repo2 repo2-b-2
git instaweb --httpd webrick
```

The server is up and running now and the homepage will list a .git project (which is the empty repository you just initialised) along with the two actual projects you linked to.

Comment: This is an awesome snippet, but the `instaweb` repo is going to be shared as `.git`, isn't it?