# How visualice multiples repos and clone them (git instaweb, gitlist, gitlab)

Tags: git, repository, gitlab, gitlist

I have a huge collection of git bare repos and I want to be able to see the list of the repos and clone them in a public way.

I have tried the following:

- **git instaweb**. Even in doc shows that is possible to view multiple repos, but it doesn't works. I have posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305637/git-instaweb-with-multiple-repositories-not-working)
- **gitlist** only list repos. There is an [feature request](https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist/issues/328) which seems to be forgotten.
- **gitlab-ce** I'm able to sync the new repos automatically via CLI but each new repos is imported as private and I haven't found how to make it public via CLI. As the number of repos could grow or shrink, all the processes must be automatic.

Taking into account the issues mentioned previously. Is there any way to public list a collection of repos and be able to clone them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used Cgit. Very easy to set up and only with the features I was looking for.